# Where to use setCurrentTabIndex in CarbonKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have tried using `setCurrentTabIndex` method to programatically go to another view in all methods like `didMoveAtIndex`, but it gets messed up every time. Any advice how to use it ?

Comment: Can you give us an example that didn't work ? It will be better to help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (UIButton *)viewAllBtns:(int )tag {
  UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [btn setTitle:@"View All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btn setTitleColor:viewAllBtnColour forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   btn.tag = tag;
  [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(viewAllMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   
  [containerView addSubview:btn];
return btn;
}
 - (void)viewAllMethod:(id)sender {
   UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
   switch([button tag]){
     case 1:   [dashboardVc.carbonSwipeNavigation   setCurrentTabIndex:1]; break;
     case 2:   [dashboardVc.carbonSwipeNavigation   setCurrentTabIndex:2]; break;
     case 3:   [dashboardVc.carbonSwipeNavigation   setCurrentTabIndex:3]; break;
    default: break;
}
```

}

Please try this method..